# Python on windows - conhost.exe CPU usage

Tags: python, windows, cpu-usage, windows-console

I'm running a Python script on Windows, and I've noticed that even though the Python process takes ~8% CPU, the associated `conhost.exe` process takes ~14%.

Why is this so? How come such a large part of the CPU consumption is in the conhost and not in the Python process?
Is there a way to reduce this CPU consumption? (besides optimizing the code of course)

**UPDATE 1:** Win7 64bit, Python 2.6.6

**UPDATE 2:** The Python program uses a C++ package via [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) Python bindings. The C++ package ([quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/)) does I/O with the network quite a bit (1), it also prints to the console (2). The Python code prints to several files (3). Which if these three should be suspect?

Comment: Which Windows and which Python?

Comment: And this matters, because...?

Comment: Does the CPU usage in conhost.exe mostly disappear if you minimize the console window?  If so, it may be an issue with the video device driver: for example, if you are using the Microsoft generic drivers console performance is sometimes poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know what your program is doing we have to guess a little. So long as there is no I/O I'd expect `conhost` to consume 0% CPU. So I hypothesise that you are printing a lot of text to the console.  For example, the following program has the same symptoms as you report:

```
while True:
    print "Hello world!"
```

Comment: printing to console is only think that should make conhost work

Comment: Following this answer I found that diverting the output to file reduces conhost.exe's CPU consumption dramatically. So you could `script.py > output.txt` or even `script.py > nul` if you don't care to lose the output

Comment: Nice to see my suspicions confirmed.